# Typing punctuation adds an accent to the preceding letter after my laptop is docked for a few minutes

Tags: linux, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I am running Manjaro XFCE. Everything worked like a charm for months now, but 2 weeks ago the keyboard configuration from my external keyboard seems damaged.

Writing on my laptop itself works flawlessly. But when my laptop is docked and I use my usb keyboard for like 10 minutes, it suddenly starts to behave weird.

Typing <kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> yields `ė`. <kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> yields `ę`. And, there are many more. Typing with this is unbelievable disapointinġ. The last written letter is always composed with the preceding punctuation.

The only thing I can do in this case is to open my laptop lid so the screen turns on. Then I can write just as usual with my USB keyboard. Also, it changes back to normal sometimes without even doing anything.

Comment: You need to find out how to disable *compose*. Or you need to do - `stty istrip`.

Comment: I just removed Ibus packages I installed for ibus-anthy. IIRC the problem appeared since then. Let's see if this helps. Thanks for the advice with 'compose', didn't know how this was named.

Comment: oh yeah - I bet it was ibus. if you get it resolved that way will you please post it as an answer and ping me? I'll upvote it.

Comment: Nopę, compose is still active today, even though Ibus have been removed. *whelp*

Comment: `stty istrip` does not fix anything for me.

Comment: well, it won't in a terminal launched in X - X owns that terminal *and* input. have you looked at `xinput`? Also - and just for testing - have you tried loading a different desktop environment?

Comment: I find my Logitech USB Keyboard in xinput, but don't know how this could be helpful :( -- Not yet.

Comment: Okay here is the strangest thing ever. Compose is just activated in Firefox, everywhere else its not runninġ and I dont have any problems in Thunderbird or gedit and such. So I only have this damn problem inside firefox and don't know why. I already reinstalled it tho.

Comment: Oh. firefox extensions then? or something like that? Check your ~/. folders for any mozilla related cruft you can do without. Also empty ~/.cache

Comment: Neither of thosė. Deleted ~/.cache/mozilla, other cache folder is stored on /tmp due to SSD. Deactivated all addons. Tested icognito mode. Nothings workş, still having this problem.

Comment: Run the program `xev` and type `e` then `.` there. What “KeyPress” events do you see? Copy-paste the paragraphs that begin with “KeyPress event”. What model of laptop and docking station are they? Does anything related appear in the kernel logs (`/var/log/kern.log`, look for events around the time the phenomenon starts)?

Comment: Lenovo Thinkpad X240 with Ultra Dock. I cańt find kern.loġ, nothing suspicious found in `dmesg kern`. Keypress event says nothing special: 
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2a00001,

The problem only occurs in Firefox (30).

Comment: Cannot edit, here you go: http://pastebin.com/ffMYrrJe

Comment: And by the way, as the title got changed, each character I write appears underlined first, then I may type another character and the newest one will become underlined or I try to write a comma and the currently underlined character (*the latest*) gets the accent.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it. Just noticed that compose is still active in Thunderbird, it recently "activated" itself there... God damnit. Reinstall the complete system? Or any advice?

Comment: Oh hell yea. I discovered how to turn it off and on. (press space and shift). so where can I find this combination in settings so I can turn it off completely?